# Crash ConcurrentModification

Tags: android

I have ocassional crash at my emulator, but for now never on tablet on which I am testing.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException                                            
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:346)      
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:375)                
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:373)                
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1024)                                  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                              
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                                  
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1229)           
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1215)           
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)           
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1859)      
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1701)              
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1665)              
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)         
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)        
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)           
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)           
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1859)      
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1701)              
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1665)              
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1155)                             
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1114)                                    
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:479)                               
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)                                 
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:493)                                    
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityPaused(ActivityManagerNative.java:1574)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3292)          
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)                   
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)              
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                               
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)                                           
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)                         
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                              
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)                                  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)   
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)                      
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems from the log it happens when the activity is going to pause. 
All my activity are accessing a common super class static object (global data), which indeed has some linkedhashmap inside, and I am saving this globaldata with putSerializable inside onSaveInstanceState. I have tried to put save/restore of globaldata inside my base activity class inside sattic synchronized methods, but it didn't helped.

My I know from yours experiences if this is some internal android bug (maybe just emulator bug) or If I am managing saving of global data (which has LinkedHashMap inside) wrong. Or is there another way to share common data between activites?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note now passed my mind. When one activity goes to pause another one wakes up and access global data so maybe I should put save/restore on synchronized methods inside global data itself (already all global data methods are synhronized).Well I will give it a try.

Comment: Did anything helped?

Comment: I do not get any of these exceptions  from when I have changed how I delete entries from the map. It is possible that I was looping on entries and deleting meanwhile and I have found that I should avoid this, so I changed a bit.